# Проблема с передачей данных по ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, веб-программирование

на сайте передаю данные из форм по ajax. При этом нужно загружать файлы. Создаю объект FormData предварительно загрузив файл в отдельную переменную

```
$('input[name="userfile"]').change(function(e){
  new_file = e.target.files[0];
});
```

Объект FormData выглядит следующим образом

```
let formData = new FormData;
formData.append('key', value);
formData.append('file', new_file)
```

Сам ajax запрос

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    success (data) {
     //TODO;
    }
  });
```

А проблема вот в чем: кириллица при обращении на php страничке заменяется на различные символы.
Например слово "Привет" в $_POST будет отображаться как "@825B". Можете пожалуйста подсказать как это исправляется.

Comment: Забыл добавить если передавать на объект formData а просто набор ключ значениe ```$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    data: {},
    success (data) {
     //TODO;
    }
  });``` то все работает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте,

Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8